# Variably assigning new key/value pairs to object from another object in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have two objects I wish to 'compare' keys for a mongo update, and any new keys from the data sent in, I would like to add to the old doc before updating:

I have tried:

```
var updateObj = date[0];
var keys = Object.keys(req.body);
//I wish to look at the difference between req.body and updateObj

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  updateObj[keys[i]] = req.body[keys[i]];  //for the keys in my req.body, updateObj
                                           //now has that corresponding key/value in it
}
console.log(updateObj);  //i get data[0] in the console, oh no
```

but when I log updateObj in the backend, I get data[0] :(

Comment: Don't you need `updateObj[keys[i]] = req.body[keys[i]];` ? (`=` instead of `==`)

Comment: The code as you posted it will work as expected. I guess you dumped it down too much.

Comment: ya so guys, it works now. classic case of "my code doesnt work, idk why.........my works, idk why" thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update what's new and changed, then do something like this:

```js
var updateObj = data[0];
var keys = Objects.keys(req.body);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    var currentKey = keys[i];
    //Check if the key exists in the old object
    if updateObj.hasOwnProperty(currentKey) {
      if (updateObj[currentKey] !== req.body[currentKey]) {
        updateObj[currentKey] = req.body[currentKey];
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise just add the new key/value pair
      updateObj[currentKey] = req.body[currentKey];
    }
  }
```

Otherwise just loop through your req.body and assign all key/value to old object and that will overwrite the old properties.